# Node Permission base on per Taxonomy Term

Tags: nodes, users

Is it possible to give view page(or article) permission per Taxonomy term? I know there is a "Taxonomy Access Control" module but this module does not really give the permission, beside hiding the node url. Meaning I still able to see the page if I know the original url. For example, "www.mysite.com/node/100".

Comment: Are you sure TAC does not provide this? What do you mean view page permission? Are you looking to give users of role A the ability to view pages with term X, where as users of role B can view pages with term X?

Comment: I'm trying to "NOT" give user of role A(anonymous) the ability to view any pages on Term X. The problem with TAC is that, user of role A still able to view pages on Term X if they know the original URL. For example, user can type the page "www.mysite.com/node/100" url and view that page, if that node 100 is on "Term X".

Comment: Hi, Checkout this site I just spun up > http://sb8bc3b2bc0e986a.s3.simplytest.me/node/1. Access Denied, right? Login with 'test_authenticated' and 'test' and you can see it with the tag 'disallowed', which I've configured using TAC to not show to anonymous users.

Comment: I think you might have TAC mis configured or need to rebuild permissions. Can you provide specifics about how you've configured it?

Comment: I'm trying to rebuild the permission now. My setting was "D-View, I-Update, I-Delete". It may take me a while to reset because my site has over 8000+ pages.

Comment: Was your setting for a specific term for the anonymous role settings from the TAC admin page? Are you sure node 100 or other has the term that has this configuration?

Comment: Something is not right. The setting you provide does block the access for the Main(parent) term itself but not the node inside of the main term and child term. Does it have conflict with "content access" module?

Comment: So, you are using more than one access module? That's always difficult to get them to play nice. You can try https://drupal.org/project/module_grants, but not sure it will work. You many need a different approach all together.

Comment: Sorry Jason, I should mention using on Drupal 7

Comment: Maybe this is why I got "page not found" instead of "access denied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think TAC can provide this functionality.

Here's a screen shot of the TAC config.

http://cl.ly/image/1f1Z433r0y1s

Comment: Thank You Jason, your answer and respond did help me a lot. It fixed after I changed the "access control" permission on content type(page).

Comment: Great, glad you hung in there and figured it out!